# NodeJS Identify once

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want variable identify once so;

├── project_folder

|   ├── app.js //main file

|   └── router/index.js

#### app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const router = require('./router/index');
const mysql = require('mysql');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use('/',router);

app.listen( 8000, function(){
    console.log( 'Server listening on * 8000' );
});
```

#### index.js

```
//other codes
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'root',
    database : 'wordpress'
});

connection.connect(function(err){
    if(err)
        console.log(err);   
});
//other codes
```

#### error : mysql is not defined

#### I don't want identify mysql and other variables again.

How can I solve?

Thank you for your helping.

## SOLVED

Create a settings.js
Define settings in file

### EXAMPLE

```
const testSettings = "test Settings...";

module.exports = {
    test:testSettings
}
```

In a file you want
require('./settings');

### Using: settings.test

Comment: Node is modular, so you are not really supposed to create globals that way. Usually you create modules that exports something, and imports that module wherever you need it.

Comment: Just `require('mysql')` in any file you need. Trust me, it's much better that way, makes your code more modular, and is the way Node is intended to work. Making global variables is a big anti-pattern.

Comment: I don't understand exactly, what should I do

Comment: @MustafaKÜÇÜK Inside of `index.js` put `const mysql = require('mysql')` just like you did in `app.js`.

Comment: you're using mysql in index.js without requiring it

Comment: Do I have to take it on every file? thanks

Comment: @MustafaKÜÇÜK Every file that uses `mysql`, yes.

Comment: I understand, thanks for helping :)

Comment: Is not it the crowd of code that makes every MySQL connection used anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to **require('mysql')** in you index.js file.

And in your app.js file, as you have already imported this file(index.js), this will lead to the execution of this file as soon as it is required by you in app.js file. 
Therefore, you need not **require('mysql')** in the app.js file as this is the way NODE intends to work (modularizes the code).

it must be required in each file where you us mysql

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

    const connection =

 mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'root',
        password : 'root',
        database : 'wordpress'
    });

    connection.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err); 
        }  
    });
```

If you create any functions inside this index.js file which are required in other modules, you can **module.exports** them.

**Edit:**

Refer to this link for in-depth explanation on modules: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: Is not it hard to define MySQL information in every file?

Comment: Not in every file but wherever you need to use mysql

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the modules that are required:

index.js

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'root',
    database : 'wordpress'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err); 
    }  
});
```

Comment: Do I have to take it on every file?

Comment: @MustafaKÜÇÜK no, only in files where you are using `mysql` object

Answer (score 0):

As others answers pointed, you should import module using 'require()' when you want to access it in the file.

If you are asking how to initialize db connection without initializing it in every file, you can create module for db connection.

Check Dave's answer on this topic [how does createConnection work with nodeJS in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40153085/how-does-createconnection-work-with-nodejs-in-mysql)